# Boot failing to complete after resizing RAID 1 with GParted

Tags: mdadm, raid1, ubuntu-18.04, gparted

So I have the following setup in Ubuntu 18.04:

```
/dev/md0: / (ext4)
/dev/md1: swap
/dev/md2: /var/lib (ext4)
```

I needed to free a couple of GB space after /dev/md2, so I decided to live boot using SystemRescueCD, and shrunk /dev/md2 with GParted which claimed to  succeed (but the unassigned space after md2 didn't change nevertheless).

Anyway, I decided to reboot and now there is a partial boot process interrupted by several Load Kernel Modules failures wich finally drops onto Emergency Mode console:

```
[  OK  ] Started Tell Plymouth To Write Out Runtime Data.
[  OK  ] Started Show Plymouth Boot Screen.
[FAILED] Failed to start Load Kernel Modules.
See 'systemctl status systemd-modules-load.service' for details.
...
[  OK  ] Started Avahi mDNS/DNS-SD Stack.
[  OK  ] Stopped Cgroup management daemon.
[FAILED] Failed to start Cgroup management daemon.
See 'systemctl status cgmanager.service' for details.
```

Etc.

RAID1 arrays are detected and used with no problem apparently as per:

```
cat /proc/mdstat
Personalities : [linear] [multipath] [raid0] [raid1] [raid6] [raid5] [raid4] [raid10] 
md2 : active raid1 sda5[2] sdb5[1]
      296717824 blocks super 1.2 [2/2] [UU]

md1 : active raid1 sda3[2] sdb3[1]
      521856 blocks super 1.2 [2/2] [UU]

md0 : active raid1 sda1[2] sdb1[1]
      15181184 blocks super 1.2 [2/2] [UU]

unused devices: <none>
```

Also I can access all filesystems and browse through files and directories with no trouble AFAIK.

Also tried to :

```
update-initramfs -u
update-grub
```

And also (just in case):

```
dpkg --reconfigure -a
```

With no errors at all to no avail, so I'm getting a bit lost here. Any suggestions should be welcome.

Comment: [FAILED] Failed to start Cgroup management daemon.
See 'systemctl status cgmanager.service' for details.